# Open image in django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have a folder, outside of my app, that contains gigabytes of pictures. Then I need to display some of pictures listed in variable `images`. Now code looks like this:

settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/mnt/Images/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/mnt/Images/',
)
```

results.html

```
{% for im in images %}
    <img width="100" height="100" src="/mnt/Images/1/{{im}}" alt="My Image" />
    <strong>{{ im }}</strong><br>
{% endfor %}
```

It works but I'm not sure if changing `STATIC_URL` is the right way to go (otherwise it doesn't work). Is there a better way to display images from outside `BASE_DIR`

Comment: Please have a think about how this is going to work in production. Do you really want to expose your `/mnt/` tree to the internet?

Comment: So what is the correct way to work with images outside of app directory.